# How to detect the singular value with signal processing technology?

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, signal-detection

I have a signal like

> `signal={1.00,1.10,1.22,1.34,1.48,1.62,1.76,1.90,2.05,2.19,2.32,2.44,2.54,2.62,2.68,2.71,2.72,2.70,2.65,4.00,4.00,2.37,2.24,2.11,1.96,1.82,1.67,1.53,1.40,1.27,1.15,1.04,0.94,0.85,0.77,0.70,0.64,0.59,0.54,0.50,0.47,0.44,0.42,0.40,0.39,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.40,0.41,0.44,0.46,0.49,0.53,0.58,0.63,0.69,0.76,0.83,0.92,1.02,1.12,1.24,1.37,1.50,1.64,1.78,1.93,2.07,2.21,2.34,2.46,2.55,2.63,2.69,2.71,2.72,2.69,2.64,2.56,2.46,2.35,2.22,2.08,1.94,1.79,1.65,1.51,1.38,1.25,1.13,1.03,0.93,0.84,0.76,0.69,0.63,0.58,0.54,0.50,0.46,0.44,0.41,0.40,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.40,0.42,0.44,0.47,0.50,0.54,0.58,0.64,0.70,0.77,0.85,0.94,1.03,1.14,1.26,1.39,1.52,1.66,1.81,1.95,2.10,2.23,2.36,2.47,2.57,2.64,2.69,2.72,2.71,2.68,2.63,2.55,2.45,2.33,2.20,2.06,1.92,1.77,1.63,1.49,1.35,1.23,1.11,1.01,0.91,0.83,0.75,0.68,0.62,0.57,0.53,0.49,0.46,0.43,0.41,0.39,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.40,0.42,0.44,0.47,0.51,0.55,0.59,0.65,0.71,0.78,0.86,0.95,1.05,1.16,1.28,1.41,1.55,1.69,1.83,1.98,2.12,2.26,2.38,2.49}`

If I plot it,its graphics will be

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As the graphics,we can see there are two singular values in 20 or 21 approximately.I want to use techonology of wavelet analysis to find it.How to do it?Actually I can do it by *Mathematica*,my answer is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143602/21532).But I'm looking forward a *better* solution.Anyone could use any promgram,like *python*,*matlab* or other something.

Comment: Why do you want to use wavelet transform? are other signal processing techniques allowed?

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé You can have a try if the effect is good

Answer (score 2):

Use e.g. median filtering to detect the outliers (code in python):

```
data=np.array([1.00,1.10,1.22,1.34,1.48,1.62,1.76,1.90,2.05,2.19,2.32,2.44,2.54,2.62,2.68,2.71,2.72,2.70,2.65,4.00,4.00,2.37,2.24,2.11,1.96,1.82,1.67,1.53,1.40,1.27,1.15,1.04,0.94,0.85,0.77,0.70,0.64,0.59,0.54,0.50,0.47,0.44,0.42,0.40,0.39,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.40,0.41,0.44,0.46,0.49,0.53,0.58,0.63,0.69,0.76,0.83,0.92,1.02,1.12,1.24,1.37,1.50,1.64,1.78,1.93,2.07,2.21,2.34,2.46,2.55,2.63,2.69,2.71,2.72,2.69,2.64,2.56,2.46,2.35,2.22,2.08,1.94,1.79,1.65,1.51,1.38,1.25,1.13,1.03,0.93,0.84,0.76,0.69,0.63,0.58,0.54,0.50,0.46,0.44,0.41,0.40,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.40,0.42,0.44,0.47,0.50,0.54,0.58,0.64,0.70,0.77,0.85,0.94,1.03,1.14,1.26,1.39,1.52,1.66,1.81,1.95,2.10,2.23,2.36,2.47,2.57,2.64,2.69,2.72,2.71,2.68,2.63,2.55,2.45,2.33,2.20,2.06,1.92,1.77,1.63,1.49,1.35,1.23,1.11,1.01,0.91,0.83,0.75,0.68,0.62,0.57,0.53,0.49,0.46,0.43,0.41,0.39,0.38,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.37,0.38,0.39,0.40,0.42,0.44,0.47,0.51,0.55,0.59,0.65,0.71,0.78,0.86,0.95,1.05,1.16,1.28,1.41,1.55,1.69,1.83,1.98,2.12,2.26,2.38,2.49])
data_index = np.arange(len(data), dtype=int)

### Outlier detection begin
filtered = signal.medfilt(data, 5)
diff = abs(data - filtered)
meandiff = np.mean(diff)
stddiff = np.std(diff)
outliers = diff > (meandiff + 3*stddiff)
print ("Outlier indices:", data_index[outliers])
### Outlier detection end

plt.plot(data_index, data, label='data')
plt.plot(data_index, filtered, label='filtered')
plt.plot(data_index[outliers], data[outliers], 'ro', label='detected outliers')
plt.legend()
plt.ylim((0,5)); plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much,if there is not better method,I will accept it. :)